# does the param 'coef0' mean a specific coefficient in sklearn.svm.SVC method?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

In machine learning, [support-vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine)s

> are supervised learning models with associated learning algorithms
>   that analyze data used for classification and regression analysis.

sklearn provides `svm.SVC` to do the work.

does the param 'coef0' mean a specific coefficient for some scenarios? if yes, what coefficient it is?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC), `coef0` is an

> Independent term in kernel function. It is only significant in ‘poly’
>   and ‘sigmoid’.

In fact, you can see it as a term in the definition of [Kernel functions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#kernel-functions):

- polynomial: `powi(gamma*dot(x[i],x[j])+coef0,degree)` (C syntax from `libsvm`)
- sigmoid: `tanh(gamma*dot(x[i],x[j])+coef0)` (C syntax from `libsvm`)

Roughly speaking, it controls how much the model is influenced by high-degree polynomials.